# onRequestPermissionsResult not called in Fragment, log not printed

Tags: android, permissions

I know there's a lot of similar questions, but either I just keep misunderstanding all answers, or they don't work for me.

The class where this code belongs to extends `Fragment`.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    // THIS LOG IS NEVER PRINTED!
    Log.v("TAG_NR_331", "CODES: " + requestCode + ", " + MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
}
```

The log is never printed.

Comment: make sure you call the correct manifest

Comment: This is the manifest import: `import android.Manifest;`

Comment: if you use android-studio it will appear from where you import it, and there are 2

Comment: There's only one import shown. And I've tried changing the code up to `android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA` (which can't be ambiguous), and it doesn't change anything

Comment: have you seen what appears on the console?, some Error?

Comment: No, nothing occurs